# Generating a NSURL from a PHAsset in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get a URL (if this framework is similar to AL) so that I can get my app to select a image from a gallery and ship that image.

Is there a way to do this (or can I already select the exact file from disk using PHAssets)?

Comment: Assets contain only metadata. The underlying image or video data for any given asset might not be stored on the local device. However, depending on how you plan to use this data, you may not need to download all of it. For example, if you need to populate a collection view with thumbnail images, the Photos framework can manage downloading, generating, and caching thumbnails for each asset. For details, see PHImageManager Class Reference.

Comment: Say I want to ship it to my off-phone server to do some image processing.
Will this be a problem?

Comment: You would need to load it first

Comment: ^Please elaborate a little more on that.
Thanks so much

Comment: I still haven't used PHAsset but it is probably because of how iCloud Photo Library works.

Comment: Eh, I'd still like to know if there's a way to access the NSURL of an Asset in swift if possible.
Thanks though.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Request_Info_Keys

Comment: take a look at To edit a PHAsset object’s photo or video content: